# Redirect on same page with more complex url using getStaticProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I use Next.js. I have a page `/blog/id` But when browser open it, I need to redirect on this page with the same content, but with a url like `/blog/id/slug`.

I'm trying to do redirect, but I have 404

I have code like this

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps<DynamicPageProps> = async ({ locale, params }) => {
  const article = await getArticlePage(params.slug)

  return {
    redirect: {
      destination: `blog/${article.id}/${params.slug}`,
      permanent: true
    },
    props: {
      slug: params.slug,
      article 
    },
    revalidate: 120
  }
}
```